# Display weekly data horizontally

Tags: php, mysql

I'm reciving  data from 2 table  staff table and booking table
Booking table has foreign key staff_id used 2 join tow tables.
I would like to display them as in the image below. here is my pseudo code. any help much appriciated

Group by is not an option.
the function  DaysinWeeks($staff_id) has sql
$sql = 'Select start_date, end_date,location ,  DAYOFWEEK(start_date) as week where staff_id = {$id}';

[image]

```
 <table class="table">
   <tr>
      <th> Staff  </th>
      <th> Monday (day) </th>
      <th> Tuesday (day)</th>
      <th> Wednesday  (day)</th>
      <th> Thursday  (day)</th>
      <th> Friday (day)</th>
      <th> Saturday (day)</th>
      <th> Sunday  (day)</th>
   </tr>
   <?php foreach($allemp as $row): ?>
   <tr>
      <td> 
         <b> <?php echo $row->firstName; ?> , <?php echo $row->lastName; ?></b> <br>
         <?php echo $row->id; ?>
         <br>
      </td>
      <?php   foreach($DaysinWeeks($row->id) as $rows): ?>
      <?php if($rows->week == 3 ):
         ?>
      <td>
         Tuesday
         <?php   //  // out put data  for  this date  ?>
      </td>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if($rows->week == 4 ): ?>
      <td>
         Wednesday
         <?php   //  // out put data  for  this date  ?>
      </td>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
```

Comment: hi, you could perhaps [group by in php](https://github.com/jakezatecky/array_group_by/blob/master/src/array_group_by.php)

Comment: why do you not post  a [mre] so that we can buid a query or you look for pivot as yourtable is fixed you don't need dynamic sql at all